# how to secure only one url with spring security and permit all

Tags: java, spring-security, springfox

Im trying to configure Spring security to block only request to swagger, however it is blocking all urls.
Does anyone know how to only lock the swagger's url and leave all the rest not secured?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/swagger*/**").authenticated();

        http.httpBasic();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that blocking everything but swagger?

Comment: this is bloking my post localhost:8012/bus/refresh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/swagger*/**").authenticated()
.anyRequest().permitAll()
.and()
.csrf().disable();
```

This should only authenticate swagger but permit the rest of the requests.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you intent ?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/swagger*/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();            

    http.httpBasic();
}
```